# Access variable in vue custom renderer

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, word-cloud

I am trying to implement te custom renderer of this Vue Word Cloud component in Laravel:
https://github.com/SeregPie/VueWordCloud

I first prepare my word array using php (working):

```
        @php
            $tags = App\Models\Tag::withCount('songs')->orderBy("songs_count", "desc")->take(50)->get();
            $words = "";
            foreach($tags as $tag)
            {
                $count = $tag->countSongs();
                $words .= "['$tag->name', $count],";
            }
        @endphp
```

Then I include the word cloud (this is working)

```
    <vue-word-cloud
        style="
            height: 480px;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        "
        :words="[{{ $words }}]"
        :color="([, weight]) => weight > 40 ? 'Red' : weight > 30 ? 'Orange' : weight > 20 ? 'Seagreen' : weight > 10 ? 'White' : weight > 5 ? 'LightSkyBlue ' : 'White'"
        font-family="Nunito"
    >   
    
    </vue-word-cloud>
```

But when I try to use the custom renderer like this: (I need this to wrap a link around every word)

```
    <vue-word-cloud
        style="
            height: 480px;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        "
        :words="[{{ $words }}]"
        :color="([, weight]) => weight > 40 ? 'Red' : weight > 30 ? 'Orange' : weight > 20 ? 'Seagreen' : weight > 10 ? 'White' : weight > 5 ? 'LightSkyBlue ' : 'White'"
        font-family="Nunito"
    >   
      <template slot-scope="{text, weight, word}">
        <div>
          @{{ text }} <!-- this is not working, I need a link around the word here -->
        </div>
      </template>       
    </vue-word-cloud>
```

It produces the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

I am by no means a VUE.js expert and maybe I am missing something trivial.
How can I access the custom renderer's "word" variable

Comment: are you using Vue3 or Vue2 ?

Comment: If incase you are using Vue3 the replace `slot-scope` with `v-slot`.

Comment: I am using Vue3. @Ali, holy moly, that fixed my problem, please post it as an answer and I will accept it! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Adrenaxus this is what I about to share https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

Comment: Thank you all for providing the working fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `scope-slot` with `v-slot` and it will work.
Here is the [reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots).

Comment: You're too late to the party.

Comment: Thank you, Ali! Unfortunately I cannot accept two answers but your effort is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey, no problem at all. Your issue is resolved thats what matters.

Answer (score 1):

The `slot-scope` syntax is [deprecated since v2.6](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-scope-deprecated). Use `v-slot` instead:

```html
<template v-slot="{text, weight, word}">
```